# DOMXPath PHP Class name change dynamic

Tags: php, domxpath

I used DOMXPath to get some text information from a website.

```
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
@$domDocument->loadHTMLFile($url);            
$xpath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$elements = $xpath->query('//span[@class="uqkIZw ka2E9k uMhVZi dgII7d z-oVg8 _88STHx cMfkVL"]');
```

Every time when I start the script I get and error because the span element was not found. I looked at the website and the class name has changed to = uqkIZw ka2E9k uMhVZi FxZV-M z-oVg8 pVrzNP. It seems like when something changes on the website it will automatically change the class names of elements. Is there any possibility to get an element with DOMXPath when the class name are changing?

Comment: This seems a common method to stop people scrapping the web sites, so the idea is to make it difficult.  You could look for some text which is constant, but at some point this may also change.

Comment: You need to find another way to identify the element you want. Probably the website is doing this to avoid scrapping.